# Unable to browse internet in Genymotion via VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I have installed Oracle VirtualBox and Genymotion..  I installed Google Nexus using Geymotion inside the VM. I have ethernet LAN networking in my hostel, but I can't connect Google Nexus VM to the Internet. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect your device to a network, apparently Genymotion requires a licensed version which costs about $299. If you find a solution, please let me know. I like Genymotion emulator, and the Android Studio emulator is way too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not really with the free personal account you can connect to the internet on any guest OS on GenyMotion. Under network settings in VirtualBox ensure set the Adapter 1 setting to `Host-only Adapter` then switch on wifi in the Android OS of the guest device. The Android device should now connect to the host network as wifi.